# multiline datagridviewcell while in edit mode

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, multiline

I am using the following code so that gridview cell support multiline while in edit mode :

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
   ((DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl)e.Control).AcceptsReturn = true;
}
```

when I press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+ <kbd>ENTER</kbd> ,gridviewcell provides newline but whole content of cell is not displayed as current line moves up and displays only one line at a time at which your text caret is blinking.

Is there anyway I can show whole editing cell with multiline while in edit mode itself?

Comment: increase the height of grid row

Comment: but how can i increase row height while in edit mode..?

Answer (score 0):

try this....

The best way is by handling the EditingControlShowing event of the grid and add the following code

```
if ((e.Control.GetType() == TextBox))
{
   TextBox txtB = new TextBox();
   txtB = e.Control;
   txtB.Multiline = true;
   txtB.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Both;
}
```